# If $a_1a_2\cdots a_n=1$, then the sum $\sum_k a_k\prod_{j\le k} (1+a_j)^{-1}$ is bounded below by $1-2^{-n}$

Tags: inequality

I am having trouble with an inequality.  Let $a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_n$ be positive real numbers whose product is $1$.  Show that the sum
 $$ \frac{a_1}{1+a_1}+\frac{a_2}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)}+\frac{a_3}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)(1+a_3)}+\cdots+\frac{a_n}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)\cdots(1+a_n)}$$

is greater than or equal to $$ \frac{2^n-1}{2^n}$$

If someone could help approaching this, that would be great. I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Generally, words like "tough," "hard," "difficult" aren't very useful in the title, because they give no real information. Presumably when you ask the question here, it is because you find it hard. But does it let a potential answerer know if they can help you?

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer by pressing the tick when you are happy. I realized you have not yet accepted any answer.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Also, "question" is always redundant, which left the original title with the content of "an inequality". Hope the new one is better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that  for that every positive integer $i$ we have 
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{a_i}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2) \cdots (1+a_i)} & = & \frac{1 + a_i}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2) \cdots (1+a_i)} - \frac{1}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2) \cdots (1+a_i)} \nonumber \\
& = & \frac{1}{(1+a_1) \cdots (1+a_{i-1})} - \frac{1}{(1+a_1) \cdots (1+a_i)}. \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
Let $b_i = (1+a_1)(1+a_2) \cdots (1+a_i)$, with $b_0= 0$. Then by telescopy
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left( \frac{1}{b_{i-1}} - \frac{1}{b_i} \right) = 1 - \frac{1}{b_n}.$$
Since $1+x\geq 2\sqrt{x}$ for all $x\ge 0$, we have
$$b_n = (1+a_1)(1+a_2) \cdots (1+a_n) \geq (2 \sqrt{a_1})(2 \sqrt{a_2}) \cdots (2 \sqrt{a_n}) = 2^n,$$
 with equality precisely if $a_i=1$ for all $i$. It follows that 
$$1 - \frac{1}{b_n} \geq 1 - \frac{1}{2^n} = \frac{2^n-1}{2^n}.$$

Comment: Just wondering, what do you mean "by telescopy"? I only know of telescoping sums that cancel out, not so sure of what just telescopy is. Much thanks for the answer though.

Comment: It is fairly standard jargon that covers telescoping sums and telescoping products.

Answer (score 9):

Hint: $$\frac{a_k}{(1+a_1)\cdots(1+a_k)} = \frac{1}{(1+a_1)\cdots(1+a_{k-1})} - \frac{1}{(1+a_1)\cdots(1+a_k)}$$

Comment: ... so we just have to prove that $$\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1+a_i)\geq 2^n,$$ right?

Comment: Quite right. I left that step out...

Comment: Could you let me know the name of that formula pls.

Comment: It doesn't have a name. @RealityDysfunction

Comment: It's just $$1-\frac{1}{a_k}=\frac{a_k}{1+a_k}$$ multiplied on both sides by $$\frac{1}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)\dots(1+a_{k-1})}$$

Comment: @Thomas Andrews, how high-level is this question? I guess that is pretty vague, but I'd just like to know how deep into inequality proofs this is. I've started with learning some AM-GM and such. This was a question I encountered on the past Canadian Math Olympiad questions, and I just wanted to give a go as to how close I was to starting to solve Olympiad-level problems. Also, any suggestions on books that teach how to solve these type of problems? (Ones like these that I posted). Thanks.